# Pass Variable from Parent(my domain) to iframe(Google Script)

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, postmessage

I was trying to search to find way to pass variable from parent url to child iframe(google script).

I used Post message method but it didn't work , the error is :

> dropping postMessage.. was from host https://.... but expected host https://n-......script.googleusercontent.com

my code is like the below

Parent code (JS):

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Get the window displayed in the iframe.
  var receiver = document.getElementById('Frame').contentWindow;

  // Get a reference to the 'Send Message' button.
  var btn = document.getElementById('send');

  function sendMessage(e) {
    // Prevent any default browser behaviour.
    e.preventDefault();

    receiver.postMessage('my message', 'https://script.google.com');
  }

  // Add an event listener that will execute the sendMessage() function
  // when the send button is clicked.
  btn.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
}
```

also I tried to use full google script link instead of' https://script.google.com'
`receiver.postMessage('my message', 'full google script link');`

Google Script Html Code

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Get a reference to the div on the page that will display the
  // message text.
  var messageEle = document.getElementById('message');

  // A function to process messages received by the window.
  function receiveMessage(e) {
    // Check to make sure that this message came from the correct domain.
    if (e.origin !== "my domain")
      return;

    // Update the div element to display the message.
    messageEle.innerHTML = "Message Received: " + e.data;
  }

  // Setup an event listener that calls receiveMessage() when the window
  // receives a new MessageEvent.

  window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
}
```

after hundreds of search , I found thread related to pass message from child (Google script) to parent normal html page with Google Execution API , but can't understand how it work

if there is any thing to do with post message or other method to pass simple variable from my domain (normal html page) to google script (iframe ) in same page....

Please help!!!

Comment: have your tried URL query string?

Comment: No, could you give me a clue...